# Making Access database Form more dynamic to Data Input

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm a beginner at MS Access. and I have created a local database to work on;
what I want to do is the following:

1. If the textBox named "Number" starts with specific digits, the ComboBox value to be automatically determined to x value.
   if we can replace the Combobox with just a label that automatically updates the value based on number textbox, It'd be better, aesthetically.

[image: Linking textBox input to comboBox result]

2. I want this field to be automatically counted from another list that is being input by the user himself. Instead of individually counting each approved case, it'll pull off the approved cases BASED on a specific response code "0".
   I tried this solution and it just does NOT work.

   =DCount("[Response code]","Information Subform","[Response code] = '0'")

[image: Count of approved cases]
So for example, if the user inputs data as the following, this field should return with "2" automatically instead of the user counting them manually based on Response Code = 0
[image: table example]

3. I want to my list to perform the following function: if selected a specific value, change the context of a textbox. It should act as a timesaver to write a specific dialog or script for the user.

[image: Case result example]

Comment: Item 2. Don't see anything wrong with expression. Can't explain failure. Items 1 and 2 I don't really understand. You need to do research, attempt code and when there is specific issue post more focused question with code for analysis. Question here is too broad and lacks effort.

Comment: Wait, your DCount expression references a form. Domain aggregate functions must reference table or query object not form or report. Instead of DCount, use Sum() function with IIf(): `=Sum(IIf([Response code] = '0', 1, 0))`, in textbox of subform footer, then main form textbox can reference subform textbox: `=subform container name.Form.textboxname`.

Comment: Correction, I don't understand items 1 and 3.

Comment: in addition, for 2, once you have changed dcount to reference a table or query you will probably have to change '0' to just 0.  '0' is a string, 0 is a number.

Comment: for 1. change the label's caption property in the either Number txtbox's OnChange or AfterUpdate events.  look online for examples of how to change controls in those events